# How to only wait for document.readyState in IE and fire instantly for all other browsers?

Tags: javascript

I have written a CSS and Javascript lazyloader to dynamically load resources for seperate pagelets (in the way that Facebook renders a page with it's BigPipe technology).

In short an HTML frame is rendered first, then separate parts of the page are all generated asynchronously by the server.  When each pagelet arrives the pagelets css is loaded first, then its innerHTML is set, then finally we load any required javascript for this pagelet and initialise it.

Everything works perfectly and perceived load time is pretty much instantaneous for any given page.

However in IE, I occasional I get `Method does not support method or property` when initialising the scripts.

I have solved this by checking for document.readyState before loading the scripts.

Now this isn't a huge issue but it adds on average 170ms to a pageload in chrome or firefox.  Which is not needed.

```
  function loadScripts(init){

        // ensure document readystate is complete before loading scripts
        if( doc.readyState !== 'complete'){
            setTimeout(function(){
                loadScripts(init);
            }, 1 );
        }
        else{
            complete++;
            if(complete == instance.length){            
                var scripts = checkJS(javascript);
                if(scripts.length) {
                    LazyLoad.js(scripts, function(){                    
                        runPageletScript();
                        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
                            TC.loadedJS.push(scripts[i]);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    runPageletScript();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

What I am looking for is a modification to this script which will only implement the 'wait' in IE, if it is any other browser it will just fire straight away.  I cannot use a jQuery utility like `$.Browser` and need it to be the tiniest possible method.  I hate to use any form of browser detection but it appears as though its my only solution.  That said if anyone can come up with another way, that would be fantastic.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [JScript conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/8ka90k2e%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), which is only available in IE browsers (up to IE10).

Because it's a comment, it's best to place it inside `new Function` as minifiers might remove it, changing your code. Though in general you should avoid using `new Function`, in this case there's not really any other way to prevent minifiers from removing it.

Example:

```
var isIE = !(new Function('return 1//@cc_on &0')());
```

However, it seems that your main issue is that the DOM hasn't loaded yet -- make sure that it has loaded before running any loader using the `DOMContentLoaded` event (IE9+):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // perform logic here
});
```

Comment: This is a fantastic method.  I never even knew this existed in IE.  Unfortunately the code you posted fails in IE... It's probably a simple error, i'll go through the link you provided and work out where the issue is.  If it works, it will be a perfect solution.  Do you know if this will minify correctly in googles closure however?

Comment: Sorry - I'll see where I went wrong.  Also Closure Compiler might minify it out - I'm not sure how you'd keep them.

Comment: @gordyr: I've fixed the "expected constant" error, see if it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is just another solution as the solution from Qantas might not always work. For instance on UMTS connections it could happen that providers remove comments to save bandwith (maybe they preserve conditional comments):

```
if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' 
   &&  doc.readyState !== 'complete'){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Event better...  Although Qantas solution works fine if you do the following : var is_ie = eval("/*@cc_on!@*/false");  using eval you can even get closure to compile it properly.  Regardless your solution is preferential, despite the fact that I loved finding out about conditional compilation :)